# Matlab problem merging arrays in for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, merge

from a simple code in Matlab, using a `for` loop (`for i=1:10`), I get the following 2x1 arrays:

[image: tables from for loop]

I'd like to put them all together into a 20x1 array, but I get this:

[image: final table]

As I mentioned, I'd like my final array to have the dimensions 20x1.

The code is:

```
clc
clear all
t = 1:10;
u_x = 10;
u_y = 20;
u = [u_x; u_y];

W = [];
for i=1:1:10
    w = u.*i + rand(2,1)
    W(i,:) = w;
end
W
```

Comment: You’re not using tables at all. A `table` is a specific type in MATLAB, with very different properties and functionality from the `double` array you are using. Using proper terminology is important when communicating your issues, so as to not add confusion.

Comment: Also, please don’t post images of text, they are not useful. It is so much easier to copy-paste the text itself. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `W` as you want, `W = zeros(20,1)`, and populate inside the loop as `W(2*i-1:2*i) = w` since the size of `w` is known to be `2x1`.

```
clc
clear
t = 10;
u_x = 10;
u_y = 20;
u = [u_x; u_y];
U = repmat(u, [1,t]);

W = zeros(20,1);
for i = 1:10
    w = u.*i + rand(2,1);
    W(2*i-1:2*i) = w;
end
W
```

You actually don't have to use loops, this one-liner will do the same:

```
W = reshape(repmat(1:t,2,1) .* U + rand(2,10), [20 1])
```

**Edit:** The above loop can be modified to work for any range and any step.

```
range = 1:0.5:10;
W = zeros(2*length(range),1);
for i = 1:length(range)
    w = u.*range(i) + rand(2,1);
    W(2*i-1:2*i) = w;
end
W
```

Similarly, for the vectorized solution:

```
L = length(range);
U = repmat(u, [1,L]);
W = reshape(repmat(range,2,1) .* U + rand(2,L), [], 1])
```

Comment: Your code runs fine, but it doesn't work in the case of putting a step in ''i'' (i=1:0.5:10)

Comment: @KonstantinosArvanitis -- See my updated answer for general step and range.